# Symfony2 forms - how to render all entities that can be linked to current entity with additional field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I need to implement interesting feature and i dont know the correct solution. Look at example below.

I have 2 entities:

- Vehicle (can be a car, train, bicycle or legs or something else)
- Part (it can be a coils, wheels, seat, window, handbrake etc...)

When i create or edit a Vehicle i should have possibility to choose amount of any Part for this Vehicle. So, Vehicle form should contain all of Parts and each Part should have additional field 'amount'.
So, if amount is greater than 0 then relation should be created. If Part amount equals zero - there is no relation to create between this Part and Vehicle.

Fair enough, i created additional entity to store relation with additional field:

- VehiclePart (it stores vehicle_id, part_id and amount of this part)

This entity is linked by ManyToOne relations with Vehicle and Part entities

**There is the question:** how can i render all of available Parts in Vehicle form and how can i implement check when parts amount is > 0 to persist relation?

I need an advice - what is the proper approach for my needs? And really sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach for you to try.

You could make your form using [this method from the Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html). This would work well as it would allow you to add parts to your vehicle on the fly from a select list of all available parts.

This way you would not have to worry about persisting if quantity > 0, if you add a part and a quantity, it's added. To zero the quantity you just remove the part completely.

Your original idea is not so easy. You would have to add the form fields dynamically with [form events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html). On saving your form , you could use a form event listener to access the underlying Vehicle entity and then *remove* any VehiclePart entities with a quantity of 0 before you persist your data.

This is OK to do, but I would recommend the first option as it's a lot simpler.

Edit: added basic overview. Pretty rough as I'm short on time sorry!

Listener to add a field

```
<?php

namespace Your\NameSpace\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class AddYourTypeSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory) {

        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {

        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'addYourItem');
    }

    public function addYourItem(FormEvent $event) {

        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!$data instanceof YourClass) {
            return;
        }

        /** @var YourClass $yourClassItem */
        $yourClassItem = $data;

        // You might have some criteria around what you would or would not add
        $form->add(
            $this->factory->createNamed('yourChildPropertyOrCollectionField', new YourChildPropertyOrCollectionFieldFormType() /** also could be a form type service */, null, array('auto_initialize' => false))
        );
    }
}
```

Listener to remove data related to a field based on some criteria)

```
<?php

namespace Your\NameSpace\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RemoveTypeBasedOnSomeCriteriaSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory) {

        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {

        return array(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT => 'removeItemsBasedOnSomeCriteria');
    }

    /**
     * Remove items we do not want
     *
     * @param FormEvent $event
     */
    public function removeItemsBasedOnSomeCriteria(FormEvent $event) {

        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (!$data instanceof YourClass) {
            return;
        }

        // If the form isn't valid we don't need to action this as we have
        // yet to persist.

        if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return;
        }

        // From here you can do anything with YourClass

        if ($yourClass->failsSomeCriteria()) {

            $yourClass->setSomeChildProperty(null); // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add the subscribers to the form type you'd like to attach them to.

```
    // add item subscriber in buildform method of your form type
    $addYourSubscriberSubscriber = new AddYourTypeSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
    $builder->addEventSubscriber($addYourSubscriberSubscriber);

    // remove item subscriber in buildform method of your form type
    $removeTypeBasedOnSomeCriteriaSubscriber = new RemoveTypeBasedOnSomeCriteriaSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
    $builder->addEventSubscriber($removeTypeBasedOnSomeCriteriaSubscriber);
```

Comment: Yes, yestarday i laready did with aproach you decribed just now)
So, i created PRE_SET_DATA listener to add every part to vehicle form and POST_SUBMIT listener to remove all the parts with zero price from collection.
Yes, first implementation is really easier, but the second one is more correct imho. Thank you, Richard! 
Tomorrow i'll add a code listing to help other people use this solution

Comment: @StepanYudin I was looking for something you just described. Are you still willing to share your solution? It could help others out...

Comment: @wimvds I added a basic overview - is symfony 2.3 so might not be 100% accurate for 2.7+

Comment: @wimvds do you have a working example, in the code Richard provided, I miss where to add the data that can be linked to.